# Removing two consecutive line breaks

Tags: bash, sed

My file has a lot of line breaks, like this:

```
This is a line.

This is another line.
```

I would like to remove these, but only in cases where the first line ends with `}`, e.g.:

```
\macro{This is a line.}

This is another line.
```

That should become:

```
\macro{This is a line.}This is another line.
```

How can I remove the line breaks in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I figured out:

```
$ sed -n '/}$/{h;:a;n;/^$\|}$/{H;$!ba};H;g;s@}\n*@}@g};p' input.txt
```

The idea behind is:

- Accumulate all continuous **`empty lines`** and **`lines endswith '}'`**
- Substitute **`}\n*`** with **`}`**
- Last line needs special consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an editor that support regular expressions and do a replace in your file. Replace:

```
 }$\n\n
```

with

```
 }
```

If you need to do it programmatically, the same principle applies (i.e. using regex for string replacement) but the actual answer will obviously depend on language/environment.

Comment: Many of my files are too big for a text editor to open and also, I need to remove these from many files, so this is done mostly automatically.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the bash/sed tags earlier

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed '$!N;s/}\n$/}/;P;D' file
```

if there is white space involved, try:

```
sed '$!N;s/}\s*\n\s*$/}/;P;D' file
```

or more formally:

```
sed '$!N;s/}[[:space:]]*\n[[:space:]]*$/}/;P;D' file
```